# Can a DataFrame be converted to Dataset of a case class if a column name contains a space?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark `DataFrame` where a column name contains a space. Is it possible to convert these rows into case classes?

For example, if I do this:

```
val data = Seq(1, 2, 3).toDF("a number")
case class Record(`a number`: Int)
data.as[Record]
```

I get this exception:

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`a$u0020number`' given input columns: [a number];
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:77)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.CheckAnalysis$$anonfun$checkAnalysis$1$$anonfun$apply$2.applyOrElse(CheckAnalysis.scala:74)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.trees.TreeNode$$anonfun$transformUp$1.apply(TreeNode.scala:310)
...
```

Is there any way to do this?

(Of course I can work around this by renaming the column before converting to a case class. I was hoping to have the case class match the input schema exactly.)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this solution , this worked for me without changing the column name.

```
import sqlContext.implicits._
case class Record(`a number`: Int)
val data = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val recDF = data.map(x => Record(x)).toDF()
recDF.collect().foreach(println)

[1]
[2]
[3]
```

Comment: Thanks. That's not really going to work for me though, because in my real case the data is being loaded as a `DataFrame`, it isn't coming from a `Seq`. Using `Seq.toDF` was just meant as a convenience for the example. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Spark 1.6.0.  The only part of your code that doesn't work for me is the part where you're setting up your test data.  I have to use a sequence of tuples instead of a sequence of integers:

```
case class Record(`a number`:Int)
val data = Seq(Tuple1(1),Tuple1(2),Tuple1(3)).toDF("a number")
data.as[Record] 
// returns org.apache.spark.sql.Data[Record] = [a$u0020number: int]
```

If you need a `Dataframe` instead of a `Dataset` you can always use another `toDF`:

```
data.as[Record].toDF
```